# edit template bootstrap to display 4 product image at row

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, css, laravel-5

I am developing my application with laravel5.2 .I have template with bootstrap and want to display 4 products with their pictures at each row.
this is my template

```
@extends('layouts.layout',[['subscribe'=>$subscribe]])

@section('content')
    <section id="advertisement">
        <div class="container">
            <img src="{{asset('images/shop/advertisement.jpg')}}" alt="" />
        </div>
    </section>

    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="left-sidebar">
                        @include('shared.sidebar',array('brands'=>$brands))
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-9 padding-right">
                    <div class="features_items"><!--features_items-->
                        <h2 class="title text-center">Features Items</h2>
                        @foreach ($products as $product)
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <div class="product-image-wrapper">
                                    <div class="single-products">
                                        <div class="productinfo text-center">

                                                <img src="images/shop/{{$product->image}}" height="200" width="150" alt="">
                                            <h2>{{$product->price}}</h2>
                                            <h6><p>{{$product->name}}</p></h6>


                                            <a href="{{url('cart')}}" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</a>
                                            <a href='{{url("products/details/$product->id")}}' class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-info"></i>View Details</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="product-overlay">
                                            <div class="overlay-content">
                                                <h2>${{$product->price}}</h2>
                                                <p>${{$product->name}}</p>
                                                <form method="POST" action="{{url('cart')}}">
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{$product->id}}">
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-fefault add-to-cart">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                                                        Add to cart
                                                    </button>
                                                </form>
                                                <a href='{{url("products/details/$product->id")}}' class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-info"></i>View Details</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="choose">
                                        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
                                            <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>Add to wishlist</a></li>
                                            <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>Add to compare</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
                        <ul class="pagination">
                            <li class="active"><a href="">1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">»</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!--features_items-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
@endsection
```

It is not disciplined.it display 4 at row in time and 2 in time .please help me to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have nested columns (4*x columns sm-3 inside the column sm-9) you need to wrap the 4 columns in a row so that it becomes

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach ($products as $product)
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                ...
```

Comment: I remove this div <div class="col-sm-9 padding-right"></div> and add <div class="col-sm-9"> </div> above class row  But it is the same

Comment: Hmm.. Can you post it the new code?
btw: no need to remove `padding-right`

Comment: so it worked with the proposed solution?? if yes can you select my answer as correct?